# Reading sonar sensor data in ModelPlugin without ROS

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, This is my first question here. Pardon me for any mistakes.

I have spent some time looking this over the internet but could not find a working solution yet. Documentation doesn't have much on Sonar sensors..

I am trying to read the sonar sensor `range` values which the sensor plugin, `SonarPlugin.cc` gives me and publishes to the topic `/gazebo/mtp_world/mtp_robot/left_sonar/mtp_sonar_sensor_left/sonar` in the robot's model plugin, `move_bot.cc` using a `transport` node and a `subscriber`

I got this topic from `gz topic -l` and doing `gz topic -e <this-topic-name>` gives the required range outputs along with other sonar values.

I have a very basic understanding of topics work. The message returned from the subscriber is `NULL` for this topic.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
    class MoveBot : public ModelPlugin {
        private: physics::WorldPtr world;
        private: physics::ModelPtr model;
        private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;
        private: physics::JointPtr leftJoint;
        private: physics::JointPtr rightJoint;
        private: common::Time startTime;
        private: transport::SubscriberPtr sub;

        public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /* _sdf */) {
            this->model = _parent;
            this->world = this->model->GetWorld();
            this->leftJoint = this->model->GetJoint("left_wheel_hinge");
            this->rightJoint = this->model->GetJoint("right_wheel_hinge");

            transport::NodePtr node(new transport::Node());
            node->Init();
            this->sonarTopicLeft = 
                "/gazebo/mtp_world/mtp_robot/left_sonar/mtp_sonar_sensor_left/sonar";
            this->sub = node->Subscribe(this->sonarTopicLeft, &MoveBot::cb, this);
            this->updateConnection =
                event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(std::bind(&MoveBot::OnUpdate, this));
        }

        private: void cb(ConstSonarPtr &_msg) {
            std::cout<< "callback!!!!!!!" << std::endl;
            if (_msg == NULL) {
                std::cout<< "NULL!!!!!!!" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
            std::cout << "Message: " << _msg->range() << std::endl;
        }
        private: void onUpdate() {
            // Some other code
        }
}
```

I am expecting the `cb(ConstSonarPtr &_msg)` callback to print the range values but I only get `NULL!!!!!!!` printed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26357/reading-sonar-sensor-data-in-modelplugin-without-ros/) by [akshat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39608/akshat/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solved it!

The problem was the wrong type of argument in the callback function `cb`. i.e. `ConstSonarPtr`.

I did a `gz topic -i <topic-name>` and found that the `msg` type is actually `ConstSonarStampedPtr`.

```
$ gz topic -i /gazebo/mtp_world/mtp_robot/left_sonar/mtp_sonar_sensor_left/sonar
Type: gazebo.msgs.SonarStamped

Publishers:
        192.168.1.4:39483

Subscribers:
    192.168.1.4:39483
```

FInally had to make the following changes to the `cb` callback to get the range values:

```
private: void cb(ConstSonarStampedPtr &_msg) {
    if (_msg == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    gazebo::msgs::Sonar sonarMsg = _msg->sonar();
    std::cout << "Range: " << sonarMsg.range() << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks to a post here somewhere, I found about `gz topic -i <topic-name>` and was able to solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [akshat](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39608/akshat/) with karma: 1 on 2021-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0